# Как можно присвоить id объекта другому объекту?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Всем добрый день, дан массив с объектами такого вида:
(Пользователи выбрали тип автомобилей и количество)

```
const cars = [{
  amount: 2,
  carId: "",
  type: "Легковая"
}, {
  amount: 1,
  carId: "",
  type: "Грузовая"
}]
```

После, выводится ${amount} количество форм (в данном случае 3), пользователи ввели свои данные в формы и сформировался такой массив с объектами:

```
const regDriverData = [{
  carId: 10,// одинаковый id
  driverId: 1,
  name: 'Andrew',
  type: "Легковая"
}, {
  carId: 10, //одинаковый id
  driverId: 2,
  name: 'Bob',
  type: "Легковая"
}, {
  carId: 36,
  driverId: 3,
  name: 'Jack',
  type: "Грузовая"
}]
```

Мне нужно каким-то образом наладить связь между этими двумя массивами, чтобы у объектов массива cars были заполнены carId по соотношению:

```
const cars = [{
  amount: 2,
  carId: 10,
  type: "Легковая"
}, {
  amount: 1,
  carId: 36,
  type: "Грузовая"
}]
```

Как можно решить данную задачу? Или же может изначально в массиве cars создавать carId, а после ввода данных пользователя расфасовывать carId по объектам массива regDriverData?

Comment: А по каким условиям это должно происходить? Если в исходном будет 2 легковых, то как carId должны соотноситьс? Задайте в первом объекте какой то уникальный ключ, что бы можно было их группировать

Comment: Больше это похоже на задачу для бд

Comment: По поводу бд я вас понял, но мне все равно придется решить эту задачу на стороне фронта. Подскажите пожалуйста, как бы вы решили данную задачу, я уже несколько дней кручу данные массивы. Даже не могу сообразить как сделать с уникальным ключом.

Comment: Опишите подробнее логику первого объекта, откуда появляется второй(как он из первого рождается) и как потом второй свернуть? Просто на логическом уровне. С теми данные, что есть сейчас сложно понять. Например откуда cardid = 10 взялось, по какой логике?

Comment: В данном случае есть 2 селекта (тип автомобиля и количество), пользователь например выбирает тип "легковая" и количество "1" , по клику создается массив с объектом `{amount: 1, carId: "", type: "легковая"}`, и в корзине появляется карточка c данной информацией для пользователя. Следующим шагом пользователь заполняет рег. данные автомобиля в форме. После, создается следующий объект: `{carId: "", driverId: 1, name: 'Andrew', type: "Легковая",}`. carId я создаю с помощью рандома, но не могу понять в каком объекте мне нужно создавать carId и в какой присваивать.